# Server port undefined in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I am making a Node server and running it so I am getting undefined values from dotenv file.

Here is my project structure:

```
backend
       config
            config.env
       app.js
       server.js
```

Here is the code of config.js:

```
PORT = 5000

NODE_ENV = DEVELOPMENT
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

module.exports = app
```

server.js:

```
const app = require('./app')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

//setting up confg file
dotenv.config({path:'backend/config/config.env'})
app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server started on PORT:${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} node.`)
})
```

Here is the output:

```
server started on PORT:undefined in undefined node.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you made is the in the config path, since the server.js is in the backend folder you need to use

**dotenv.config({path:'./config/config.env'})** instead of **dotenv.config({path:'backend/config/config.env'})**

```
const app = require('./app')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

//setting up confg file
dotenv.config({path:'./config/config.env'})
app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server started on PORT:${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} node.`)
})
```

Comment: it's work but i am following a tutorial from Udemy and he used backend/config.... and that's working

Comment: How old is the tutorial? He might have been using some path settings in his configurations

Comment: 6 months before and I am following that tutorial since scratch even I created this application a second time and the first time I didn't get any error

Comment: even same thing i am facing in nodemon   "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT& nodemon ./server",
    "prod": "SET NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION& nodemon ../server"
  },